# eof not recognized in Expect Script

Tags: tcl, expect

i have got some problems in my expect script.
I am spawning a scp file upload but the eof is not recognized.
The expect rans into the timeout before the script goes on.

What am i doing wrong??

Here is the script

```
    function ssh_upload_file () {

test_log INFO "Uploading File $3 to Device $2 with a $1 seconds timeout" "ssh_upload_file"
last_log_entry_to_detail

expect <<- DONE
set outfilename "$DETAIL_LOG"
log_file "$DETAIL_LOG";

set timeout $1
set lantime_ip $2

system "touch  ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
system "ssh-keygen -R $2"
spawn /bin/bash
sleep 3
send_user "Uploading File via SSH...\n"
send "scp $2 $3:$4 || echo FWTEST_SSH_RESULT=\$?\n"
expect "assword:" {
        after 1000
        send "$DUT_PWD\r"
        #set timeout 5
        #expect "y/n"
        #send "n\n"
        #set timeout $1
        #expect "#"
        #send "no_shell_timeout\n"
}
expect eof
send_user "Done."
log_file
exit 0
expect eof
DONE
LAST_ERROR=$?
return $LAST_ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spawn a bash shell, and send an scp command. When scp completes, you're sitting at a bash prompt. You need to send bash an `exit` command before you'll see `eof`.

Alternatively, you're not doing anything in that bash session except capture the output of the scp command which you can do like this:

```
spawn scp $2 $3:$4
expect "assword:" 
send "$DUT_PWD\r"
expect eof
set info [wait]
puts "FWTEST_SSH_RESULT=[lindex [set info] 3]"
```

---

Addressing Donal's comment:

```
spawn scp $2 $3:$4
expect {
    "assword:" {
        send "$DUT_PWD\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
set info [wait]
puts "FWTEST_SSH_RESULT=[lindex [set info] 3]"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot. Thought i need to spawn a bash.

Comment: In the case above, I'd combine the two expects, just in case the code gets run somewhere with RSA keys set up.