# What's the meaning of "expect <<- DONE"?

Tags: bash

What is this usage mean:

```
expect <<- DONE
...
DONE
```

as in [eof not recognized in Expect Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330074/eof-not-recognized-in-expect-script)

especially the `<<-` part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `man bash`, if you search for `<<-` (by typing: `/<<-` and `Enter`), you will find:

> ```
>    If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are
>    stripped from input lines and  the  line  containing  delimiter.   This
>    allows  here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural
>    fashion.
> ```

For example:

```
$ cat << EOF
>       hello
> there
> EOF
    hello
there
```

The same thing but using `<<-` instead of `<<`

```
$ cat <<- EOF
>       hello
> there
> EOF
hello
there
```

The leading TAB character on the "hello" line is stripped.

As the quotation from the `man` page said,
this is useful in shell scripts, for example:

```
if cond; then
    cat <<- EOF
    hello
    there
    EOF
fi
```

It is customary to indent the lines within code blocks as in this `if` statement, for better readability.
Without the `<<-` operator syntax, we would be forced to write the above code like this:

```
if cond; then
    cat << EOF
hello
there
EOF
fi
```

That's very unpleasant to read, and it gets much worse in a more complex realistic script.

Keep in mind though, as [@glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) pointed out:

> Note that only *tab characters* are removed, not arbitrary whitespace. Be careful that your text editor does not convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: Note that only *tab characters* are removed, not arbitrary whitespace. Be careful that your text editor does not convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: @glennjackman, you're right, that's good to point out, added to my post, thanks!

Comment: That's why I don't use them: I don't trust others (or myself) to maintain the tab chars. I live with  the ugly.